# Is it possible to resurface a kitchen tile floor where most of the tiles are cracked?

Tags: repair, flooring, tile

I have a kitchen floor that is made of ceramic tile. Most of the tiles are cracked. We are selling the home and having someone come and rip out the floor and install a new one will be very disruptive. Is it possible to just resurface the floor instead? Are there professionals that perform this service?

Comment: I can't think of a resurfacing option that wouldn't look and feel tacky/cheap. The only think I could think of would be to place a new engineered floor on top. Doable, but will create some transition issues with the floor elsewhere.

Comment: You could use a stick-on vinyl plank - something like [this](http://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/.North-Perry-Pine-LVP-Tranquility-15NP-KC/10039533) (just an example, not a recommendation). Requires a bit of surface prep to get it smooth & level (filling in grout lines, etc).

Comment: I'd take a discount on the price and let the new owners decide what to do.

Comment: Eric, thanks for closing the loop on your question.  As isherwood indicates, the site is structured around questions and separate answers, which helps others with a similar problem search for solutions.  Can you move your edit to an answer?  You can then accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the entire floor. It caused a lot of dust to be generated which took a while to clean up. Thanks for the comments.